# ¿Como crear saltos de linea sin usar <br> PHP?

Tags: php

No tengo mucha experiencia con php, lo que quiero es hacer saltos de linea pero sin usar `<br>`
E leido algunas preguntas similares a la mía pero no me funciona no se que hago mal.
Con esto e estado intentando pero no funciona.

```
echo 'Primer texto'.PHP_EOL.'segundo texto';
echo 'Primer texto'."\n".'segundo texto';
echo 'Primer texto'."\r\n".'segundo texto';





       <?php 
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM personas WHERE 1";
    $result = $conn->query($qry);
            $html = "";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             $nombre = $row['nombre']; 
             $apellido = $row['apellido'];
             $correo = $row['correo'];
             $telefono = $row['telefono'];
 $html.="Nombre completo:$nombre $apellido".'\n'."Nombre:$nombre".'\n'."Apellido:$apellido".'\n'."Email:$correo".'\n'."Teléfono:$telefono".'\n'."";
                        
                    }
        echo $html;
            ?>
```

Comment: `PHP_EOL` suele funcionar. ¿Dónde se mostrará el texto?

Comment: desde navegador, estoy haciendo pruebas desde phptester

Comment: Es raro que no funcione. Supongo que generas un `html` correctamente ¿no? Sería bueno que analices el código fuente que se produce. Es muy raro eso. Tanto `PHP_EOL` como `\n` suelen funcionar. Otra cosa que puede estar pasando es que tengas algún código CSS que modifique los saltos de línea.

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es enviar un correo, el cuerpo del correo no debe ser HTML, solo debe ser texto plano. E estado haciendo pruebas en http://phptester.net/ pero igual no me hace el salto de linea

Comment: Prueba con esto: `\r\n` Sigo insistiendo en que es raro, pues `PHP_EOL` funciona con casi todos los archivos.

Comment: Es cosa del sandbox que estas usando, el codigo es valido obviamente. En otros editores online como http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com o https://3v4l.org/LZHCe si funciona

Comment: Para los emails hay que enviar los encabezados correctos e igual, los clientes interpretan el HTML de forma menos versátil que un navegador. Incluye el código completo para la generación del email que envías

Comment: @A.Cedano Acabo de intentarlo pero no me da resultado

Comment: Me inclino por lo que ha indicado @Alfabravo en su comentario. Si colocas los encabezados adecuado en el email no debería haber problema. Sugiero que pulses en [edit] para ver el código que usas para mandar el email.

Comment: Tengo comentado el correo (ya que se manda desde una api). En mi código lo unico que tiene es el echo así como lo tengo en la pregunta, si se me hace raro que no considere el \n,

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias ya pude solucionarlo, tube que ponerle header('Content-type: text/plain'); y funciono, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Podrías meterlo dentro de un párrafo

```
echo '<p>Primer texto'.PHP_EOL.'segundo texto</p>';
```

Semanticamente va a ser mas eficiente tu codigo y se lee mejor, muchas veces el \n no lo toma el navegador

y si no te gusta como queda dentro de un `<p>` podrias meterle una clase css `<p class="parrafo">` y adaptarlo a tu forma, asi cada vez que lo llames ademas de tener algo correcto para cuando lo lea el navegador y adaptado a tu forma no tendras problemas y rompederos de cambeza con todos los navegadores

Answer (score 1):

### `PHP_EOL`

En PHP, tenemos el concepto de `PHP_EOL`, el cual es utilizado para crear saltos de línea de manera sencilla.

> El símbolo 'Fin De Línea' correcto de la plataforma en uso.
> (*Extraído del [manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.constants.php_)*)

La forma de uso es bastante sencilla, puedes usar esta constante predefinida de la siguiente manera:

```php
print('El valiente'.PHP_EOL.'gato maullaba feliz por la luna');
```

El resultado será algo como esto:

```
El valiente
gato maullaba feliz por la luna
```

**La principal ventaja de usar `PHP_EOL` es que se acomoda de buena manera en bastantes sistemas operativos**. Ten en cuenta que solía ser un desafío usar métodos para crear una nueva línea en la salida del código cuando se esperaba que se ejecutara en diferentes sistemas operativos. En las primeras etapas de estos sistemas, existían discrepancias significativas en los métodos para escapar caracteres. Sin embargo, con los estándares actuales, no debería haber problemas al respecto.

> Los sistemas operativos pueden tener diferentes convenciones para representar una nueva línea en el texto, como el carácter de *retorno de carro* (`\r`) y el carácter de *salto de línea* (`\n`). En el pasado, estas convenciones podían variar entre sistemas operativos, lo que causaba dificultades al escribir código que generara una salida coherente en diferentes plataformas.

Aún así, con el paso de los años y la estandarización, se han eliminado en una cantidad enorme estas discrepancias, y `PHP_EOL` es una solución efectiva.

---

### `chr()`

También es una opción viable usar la función [`chr`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.chr.php)

> Devuelve una cadena de un caracter que contiene el carácter especificado por ascii.
> (*Extraído del [manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.chr.php)*)

En este enfoque, usaremos un carácter *ASCII* para crear un salto de línea, de igual modo, funciona como una función y ha sido estandarizada.

```php
print('El valiente'.chr(10).'gato maullaba feliz por la luna');
```

En este ejemplo, usamos la función `chr()` para crear un carácter ASCII. Teniendo en cuenta la **entidad ASCII Nro. 10:**

| Entidad | Descripción corta | Representación |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 10 | *Line feed (LF)* | *nueva línea* |
| ... | ... | ... |

La salida será la misma.

```
El valiente
gato maullaba feliz por la luna
```

---

### Usar caracteres de escape

También es una buena opción usar caracteres de escape, los cuales sirven para cubrir una necesidad específica. En PHP, como en muchos otros lenguajes de programación, es posible usar `\n`, el cual representa una nueva línea en el código.

```php
print("El valiente \n gato maullaba feliz por la luna");
```

En este enfoque, usamos un *carácter escapado* para representar una nueva línea. El resultado será el mismo.

```
El valiente
 gato maullaba feliz por la luna
```

Si te preguntas por qué hay un espacio después del salto de línea; no, no es un error. Cuando usamos el `\n`, dejamos un espacio, y por eso surge el espacio que ves en el resultado.

---

### Diferencias

Si bien las tres opciones se usan para representar una línea nueva, tienen algunas diferencias que es importante notar:

- **`PHP_EOL`**: `PHP_EOL` es una **constante** predefinida de PHP. Se centra en crear una nueva línea en la salida del código, y es especial porque se adapta específicamente al sistema operativo en el que se está ejecutando la app. Es usado para asegurarse totalmente de que no hayan discrepancias y que siempre se genere una nueva línea.
- **`chr()`**: Si bien usamos `chr()` para crear una nueva línea aquí, **no es su única función.** Esta función, se usa para obtener caracteres *ASCII* con precisión.
- **`\n`**: Usar esta secuencia de escapado es una forma más práctica y fácil de lograr nuestro objetivo, y está diseñado específicamente para esta tarea, sin adaptarse específicamente a nada, será responsabilidad del sistema operativo admitir esta secuencia.

---

### Enlaces de interés y referencias

- [Constantes predefinidas en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.constants.php)
- [`chr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.chr.php)
- [Constantes en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.constants.php)
- [Lista de caracteres ASCII](https://www.techonthenet.com/ascii/chart.php)
- [Caracteres de escape](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caracteres_de_escape)